# What are the distribution options for inhouse app with less employees?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We have developed an app that works fine in Android and iOS and we tried to distribute in App store for one our customer. Since it is an in house usage app, Apple rejected it.

Our customer has less than 80 employees. So they are NOT eligible to purchase enterprise license for in house distribution either (so we purchased developer license).

Currently we deployed the app for users (only 20 users) using Adhoc method (connected the device in mac to deploy).

But they want to put the app in a centralized place where new users can download it and install it in their phone without connecting the device to mac (they need us on site to do it).

What are our options?
What is the apple business manager? will that help us?

Appreciate your help.

thanks,
Sri

Comment: you need to look at Mobile Device Management services - Intuine, AirWatch, MobileIron, etc.  There are a LOT of them out there

Comment: Further to @Jason's comment, you can submit your app as a custom B2B app in App Store connect. Your customer then enrols in Apple Business Manager (free) and you can make the app available to them in AppStore connect.  They can then use an MDM to push the apps to their devices.

Comment: As far as I know, Apple is very reluctant to give new Enterprise licenses to clients. If the user count is more than 100 Apple always asks clients to use Apple Business Manager if it is not a public App. For your case, you can use Adhoc distribution using the Apple developer program and install App using OTA installation method. Check 'Install using OTA Deployment' section in the following page. https://docs.monaca.io/en/products_guide/monaca_ide/deploy/non_market_deploy/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distribute application for inhouse for some time then please find below link where it will be work for android and iOS both platform and you can provide app version app update with same link.

https://appho.st/

You need to upload latest apk and ipa file and generate link with those file and share it with inhouse tester and client.

For new app version update just upload new apk/ipa file with same account and provide same link to inhouse tester and client.

Apart from it if you have apple developer account then i suggest please use tesflight public tester link.

For android google play account please use open beta testing feature and generate link with it.